# how to use sendgrid in web application to send mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, sendgrid

Im new to the sendgrid, i want to send email from my web application using sendgrid..i tried to follow the steps given in their documentation but on run my application goes in infinity loading

I also have set up environment variable "SENDGRID_API_KEY" with my key value in my system

this is my code:

```
        public void sendmail()
        {
            Execute().Wait();   
        }
        static async Task Execute()
        {
                var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
                var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
                var from = new EmailAddress("myemil@email.in", "sent");
                var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
                var to = new EmailAddress("myemil@email.in", "received");
                var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
                var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
                var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
                var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
```

Comment: which version of API are you using? and what response you get on this line   var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

Comment: Note that `Wait` is synchronous. You might want to review your `sendmail` method.

Comment: I've seen issues like this when calling async methods in ASP.Net from non-async methods. You should make sure that it's async methods all the way down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ConfigureAwait(false):

```
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
```